# iPhone 5s: Have to wait before I swipe after unlock animation is done

Tags: ios, iphone, ui

I use the iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1.2.

When I unlock the phone with my finger print, there is an animation where the icons move from the edges towards the center of the screen. After this animation is done, I have to wait approximately an entire second before I can swipe left/right on the touch screen in order to get to the apps on the other screens.

This is extremely annoying! Simple and quick tasks such as checking on emails will take far longer because I have to wait. This is very annoying and there is simply no way to avoid this and I don't know why Apple didn't fix this already. That's the first thing I ever noticed after buying this phone.

Will this be fixed? Is there any reasonable workaround (I don't want to install jailbreaks) ?
I know that the out-of-the-box iPhone 5s doesn't do this that way. After you install the latest iOS, the error occurs (maybe it's a "feature"?)

This isn't a bug that's only on my phone. I did reset it once (out of other reasons) and the bug was still there. Later on my phone got stolen, so I bought a new one and it was *still* there.

According to ActMonitor, I have 230 MB RAM free plus 100 MB RAM inactive. There is also 3.6 GB storage available (out of 16 GB)

Take a look at 7:31 [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBEaG6n0XDs&t=7m31s). There you can also see it, but not as extreme as with my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a solution (I doubt there is one, at least without jailbreaking), but it seems you can open apps immediately. So I would recommend putting those apps that you want to be able to open right away every time you check your phone like email on the bottom, so that they are always there.

It also looks like pressing the home button to swipe all the way left to the first home screen does not have a delay, so you could put apps on the first home screen and press the home button after unlocking (which is easy as you finger is already there). When I tested it it seemed pretty easy to accidentally activate Siri, so you might want to disable her if you do this if you don't use her.

Comment: I already have the most important apps in my bar and the second most important on my first page. But even when I click on the app, it would still open only after the animation is done (+1 second).

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it looks to me like this is an actual loading time. If it is, it won't be possible to remove it.